# How should I run a directory of CGI scripts which need PATH_INFO on Apache 2.4?

Tags: apache-2.4, debian-jessie

With Apache 2.2 I was running Mailman's CGI web interface in a VirtualHost which had:

```
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/">
               AssignUserId www-data www-data
               AllowOverride None
               Options ExecCGI
               AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
               Order allow,deny
               Allow from all

    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/lib/mailman/archives/public/">
               AssignUserId www-data www-data
               Options FollowSymlinks
               AllowOverride None
               Order allow,deny
               Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/usr/share/images/mailman/">
               AssignUserId www-data www-data
               AllowOverride None
               Order allow,deny
               Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias "/mailman/"  "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/"
```

This worked fine. Recently, perhaps after an update to Apache 2.4 in Jessie (2.4.10-10+deb8u7) I am finding that I get no content from Apache. After a lot of head scratching and after debugging mailman (1:2.1.18-2+deb8u1) I find what works is to replace the ScriptAlias with a bunch of ScriptAliasMatch statements and modify Mailman to use **REQUEST_URI** rather than **PATH_INFO** since **PATH_INFO** is undefined. Perhaps that's because I'm ScriptAliasMatch, but if ScriptAliasMatch swallows the trailing path components that would seem to limit its usefulness.

Specifically, I hacked the site to work with the rather inelegant:

```
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/">
               AssignUserId www-data www-data
               AllowOverride None
               Options ExecCGI
               AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
               Order allow,deny
               Allow from all

    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/lib/mailman/archives/public/">
               AssignUserId www-data www-data
               Options FollowSymlinks
               AllowOverride None
               Order allow,deny
               Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/usr/share/images/mailman/">
               AssignUserId www-data www-data
               AllowOverride None
               Order allow,deny
               Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias "/mailman/images/" "/usr/share/images/mailman/"
    #       ScriptAlias "/mailman/"  "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/"
    ScriptAliasMatch "/mailman/admin/(.*)"  "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/admin"
    ScriptAliasMatch "/mailman/admindb/(.*)"  "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/admindb"
    ScriptAliasMatch "/mailman/confirm/(.*)"  "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/confirm"
    ScriptAliasMatch "/mailman/create/(.*)"  "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/create"
    ScriptAliasMatch "/mailman/edithtml/(.*)"  "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/edithtml"
    ScriptAliasMatch "/mailman/listinfo/(.*)"  "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo"
    ScriptAliasMatch "/mailman/options/(.*)"  "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/options"
    ScriptAliasMatch "/mailman/private/(.*)"  "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/private"
    ScriptAliasMatch "/mailman/rmlist/(.*)"  "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/rmlist"
    ScriptAliasMatch "/mailman/roster/(.*)"  "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/roster"
    ScriptAliasMatch "/mailman/subscribe/(.*)"  "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/subscribe"
```

I then patched Mailman's function that uses PATH_INFO to fall back to REQUEST_URI:

```
def GetPathPieces(envar='PATH_INFO'):
    path = os.environ.get(envar)
    if path is None:
        path = '/'.join(os.environ.get('REQUEST_URI').split('/')[3:]).split('?')[0]
    if path:
        if CRNLpat.search(path):
            path = CRNLpat.split(path)[0]
            syslog('error', 'Warning: Possible malformed path attack.')
        return [p for p in path.split('/') if p]
    return None
```

I've read the docs on ScriptAlias and mod_cgi, and tried to be sure by adding to my VirtualHost:

```
    AcceptPathInfo on
```

which didn't help. I've also looked through the extensive apache configuration for this server and didn't find anything that looked relevant.

Also seemingly not relevant but close by is a wordpress .htaccess in the DocumentRoot of the VirtualHost

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

My question is: **how do I run an unmodified copy of Debian Jessie Mailman againgst Apache 2.4. Or, have I hit a bug in Apache? The Mailman behavior seems reasonable.**

Comment: This is likely unrelated, but you need to update your config syntax for 2.4, especially for the `Order` and `Allow` statements. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Comment: Indeed; however I already tried to work through those.

Answer (score 0):

For a Perl CGI script I use, the following configuration works with Apache 2.4.51 from SLES12, but it triggers some `AH01630` ("client denied by server configuration") errors while it works:

```apache-config
...
<VirtualHost FQHN:443>
    DocumentRoot "/srv/www/HN"
    ...
    ScriptAlias /alias /srv/www/cgi-bin/CGI.pl
    <Location /alias>
        SetHandler perl-script
        PerlResponsehandler ModPerl::Registry
        ...
    </Location>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Maybe that helps for Python, too.